# Insert some variable columns with constants

Tags: sql, variables, insert, constants

What I'm looking to do with my code is insert some variable number of rows into test_table where 'policy' in source_table matches 'bond_ser' in policy_custsgt and 'SNL_ID' in source_table matches 'inst_key' in raw_table.

I want it to insert serial_number and ID along with some other constants. I can get it to insert serial_number and ID just fine, but how do I get it to add some constants in other fields of the table every time it inserts the variables from the other tables?

This is the code I currently have, if I remove the "'122812', '999999', 'myname'" from the first line it works fine but will only populate the serial_number and ID columns of my table with each insert.

```
INSERT INTO test_table(serial_number, ID, '122812', '999999', 'myname')
SELECT policy, SNL_ID
FROM source_table
WHERE (policy IN (SELECT bond_ser from policy_custsgt)) AND 
(SNL_ID in (select inst_key from raw_table))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I over looked the simple solution. All I needed to do was move those constants I wanted down from the INSERT statement to the SELECT statment, and add the column names in the INSERT so:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(serial_number, ID, starting_date, ending_date, user_id)
SELECT policy, SNL_ID, '122812', '999999', 'myname'
FROM source_table
WHERE (policy IN (SELECT bond_ser from policy_custsgt)) AND 
(SNL_ID in (select inst_key from raw_table))
```